# Vault returns CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_ERROR when authenticating with tls

Tags: python, ssl, hashicorp-vault

I am newbie to vault and currently trying to enable client tls authentication (all on the only CentOS 7 node) via self-signed certificates.

Of course, first of all i ran: `vault auth-enable cert`

Then, I created a `policy.hcl` file with such contents:

```
path "secret/policy/test/foo" {policy="read"}
```

Then I did the following:

```
$ vault policy-write test policy.hcl
$ vault write "secret/policy/test/foo" vaule=s3cr3t policy=test
```

Generate client certificate:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -signkey client.key -out client.crt
```

And the final action:

```
$ vault write auth/cert/certs/test display_name=test policies=test certificate=@/home/vagrant/ssl/client.crt
```

And it all execute without any errors or warnings. Then, i wrote a simple script which must read just a one value after authentication with TLS:

```
import os
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='https://127.0.0.1:8200', cert=('client.crt', 'client.key'))
print(client.read('secret/policy/test/foo'))
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8200): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/secret/policy/test/foo (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)'),))
```

Server log says:

```
http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:33744: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority
```

Any help is highly appreciated

**EDIT:**

to clarify what the actual problem is, I'd like to mention that when i authenticate to the Vault using CLI:

```
$ vault auth -method=cert -client-cert=client.crt -client-key=client.key
# returns:
The token below is already saved in the session. You do not
need to "vault auth" again with the token.
token: 8afdb5bd-b6f1-e33e-a391-ced99fa18b5f
token_duration: 2764800
token_policies: [default test]
```

... it seems to be working just fine cuz the policy I've created is being attached and I can read the data from `secret/policy/test/foo`, but Python+HVAC approach does not work.

Comment: I suspect this might be a problem with the **server** tls certificate verification. How do you tell the vault CLI what certificate to use to verify the server? Are you using the `VAULT_CACERT` env var? Check that whatever method you are using is also working from python - try running your script without client-certificates involved